# Inaccurate shading on object

Tags: modeling

[image: Bottom of my torus has awful surface quality]

I am relatively new to Blender so please excuse me if this is rather amateur!

The bottom of my torus has poor surface quality, I have scaled the vertices down for a smaller (variable) tubular radius all the way around the torus and at the bottom the surface quality is awful, with inaccurate shading. Any ideas as to what is wrong and/or how I could fix this?

Thanks,
itsanate

Comment: It could be due to a few vertices that are connected inside the model and creating weird faces.
or some flipped normals. An explanation for normals [here](https://youtu.be/ui5kaAbLrso?t=75)

Comment: On a different note.. is that a DB10 steering wheel? :)

Comment: Yes it is, ᴊᴀᴄʜʏᴍ ᴍɪᴄʜᴀʟ :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

These look like inverted faces.

Check your *Face Orientation* through the *Overlay* menu.
They should all be pointing outwards (blue color).

You can recalculate them through:
*Mesh > Normals > Recalculate Outside*

[image]