# How do I make this connection look smooth?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, object-mode

I can't make these connect smoothly even though I have done the same thing multiple times and it has looked smooth. The meshes are connected properly. I have tried moving vertices in the mesh, and modifiers like subdivision surface and smooth but I can't get it to work

[image: Connection of two tubes]

Comment: Face normals issue. In edit mode, select all and shift+N.

Comment: Also, it'd be great if you show a picture with the wireframe.

Comment: Hello and welcome :). As others said, this could be caused by inverted faces  https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/165080/78972