# Mesh looks transparent and is streaky in some places

Tags: mesh, 3d-view

Does anyone know what is wrong with the mesh and how to fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello :). This could be caused by too large clipping distance in Sidebar > View > Clip Start/End.

Comment: I am not shure, but I dont think thats the problem. Even when I zoom out I can still see the transparency. The weird thing is it looks normal when in object mode.

Comment: Zooming out doesn't really affect it :). Try decreasing the *Clip End* value. Or you can [share the .blend](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) if that won't work.

Comment: I ve tried changing it but it didn't help it changed a litle bit, but it didn't solve the problem. Can you you please take a look at it.

Comment: Sure. It was mainly caused by inverted faces https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/165081/78972. I didn't know that can affect it :).

Comment: Thank you a lot it really fixed the problem. I dind't even know faces coulb be inverted.