# Blender - Material isn't applied on one part of my UV map

Tags: materials, uv, color

I got a problem when I was applying a normal map on my object. Material color isn't applied on one part of my UV Map. It is applied but from the other side and I don't know how to fix that.[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome :). Normal maps sometimes work better when saved into file (.tiff/.exr) and loaded back as an image texture. It's also important to then set it to *Non-color* and select the matching UV map. Would that help?

Comment: that didn't help

Comment: In that case, perhaps checking [Normals orientation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/165081/78972) would be my next step :).

Comment: normals seems good, but when I rotate my object 180 degrees problem disappears and appears again on the other side. I don't know where's the problem.

Comment: Well, since I'm obviously not good at guessing, consider [sharing the .blend](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), so others can take a look. Just the one problematic part, with the normal map packed.