# Turn two planes into a volume

Tags: modeling, mesh

I would like to turn two regular spaced grids (so same amount of vertices, spaced at regular intervals) into a volume in which the top plane becomes the top of the volume and the bottom plane the bottom of the volume.

[image: top and bottom plane]

I've succesfully done this duplicating the two planes (save for later), then join the original two planes and then in edit-mode -> "Bridge faces". This would remove both planes and leave me with he outer band of the volume (see image)

[image: outerband of the volume after bridging the faces of the planes]

I then placed the outer band between the previously duplicated planes. Job done.

[image: Outerband with the original planes]

But this is a bit of a pain in the neck because i would like to do this for a lot of sets of planes. And also do this with irregular spaced planes and regular spaced planes with a different extend.

Is there a method or workaround to do this more easily?

[image]

Comment: Are the top and bottom faces exactly the same ? Have you tried the solidify modifier ?

Comment: No, they are not exactly the same. X and Y values of the vertices are the same (so vertex n of the top plane lies exactly above the vertex n of the bottom plane). But the Z values are different. The two planes are basically two different height maps.  In fact, they are depth maps of a geological model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Bridge Edge Loops* should work here.

1. Join both planes into one object through *Object > Join*, <kbd>Ctrl+J</kbd>
2. Use *edge* selection and go *Select > All by Trait > Non Manifold* (to select the loops)
3. Then *Edge > Bridge Edge Loops*

[image]

*Edit:*
In your case, the mesh has two forgotten edges in one of it's corners (one on each plane). Just delete them an it will work no problem.
After all that you can [recalculate normals](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/165081/78972) so they're all pointing the right way

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for showing me the Bridge edge loop trick! I've tested this but I end up with only one side being closed.

Comment: Hello :). If it doesn't work, consider sharing your file. There could be many reasons and I'm not that good at guessing :).

Comment: How do is share a file?

Comment: You can use our [Blend-Exchange service](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) or Dropbox, Gdrive...

Comment: Thanks, i've added the Blender Exchange link to the original message.

Comment: Hey :). There are two little edges sticking out. Delete them and it will work. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to make the two elements a single object. **No vertices can belong to two different objects**.

Using bridge edge loops doesn't work because of two sets of vertices on two different corners. Bridge edge loops works only with closed loops.

There is a lonely vertex with no faces that cannot be part of a closed loop

[image]

Then, there is a single quad on some other corner. Technically that quad in itself is a closed loop, so if you use bridge edge loops that is the only loop that will get new faces.

[image]

So you can simply ignore those (or delete them) as part of the selection at the edge and use bridge edge loops successfully.

[image]

If you still need faces for the elements on the corners, add faces manually.

---

Now as a comment of workflow used in the original question, it is still valid, but will result in duplicated edges and disconnected geometry so it is not "job done" but "almost done" to finish the job you need to use "merge vertices by distance". All vertices should be then connected as part of the same object.

Comment: Good eye :). That's why using *edge selection* (not vertex selection) is very useful here - no problems with single vertices or quads :). Try it.

Comment: Many thanks to both of you no-can-do and @Jachym_Michal. I did not spot that lonely vertex and the single quad. Thanks for pointing them out. And thanks for the way to improve my first method, even though I will not use the bridge-face method anymore now. Good to know how things work.

Comment: To select the edges use "Select All by trait"  -> "non manifold"

Comment: @AndyFK Please don't add thank you as a comment, upvote the answer instead. If you feel it completely solved your problem consider marking it accepted