# When I press F I'm getting sharp corners, they should be smooth like the others

Tags: subdivision-surface

When I'm pressing f to fill the empty place I'm getting those two sharp corners and I don't know what to do ... I'm a beginner and honestly, I don't know how to google my problem cause I don't know...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello :). Perhaps some of your faces are inverted. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/165081/

Comment: and... how do I solve this?

Comment: Click the link :).