# What is causing the change in refraction with this glass?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, light, glass

I'm working on a render of a wine glass. I'm feeling pretty good about everything so far, but I can't seem to figure out how to adjust the geometry or material settings to solve the hard change in refraction that starts halfway up the glass.

I looked into some common issues with glass — adjusting maximum light paths, edge split instead of subsurf modifiers. And they helped quite a bit with the wine itself, but the glass remains befuddling.

Glass settings are simply: Glass BSDF, Beckmann, 0 Roughness, 1.45 IOR.

Here are a few photos. The render. The object. And an edit mode screenshot with the edge selected.

[image: wine glass render]

[image: object]

[image]

Comment: Are you using any modifiers currently on it?

Comment: Just a blind guess - make sure normals are correct https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/165080/78972

Comment: @Nate_Sycro27 nope - no modifiers!

Comment: @JachymMichal normals look correct. always a good blind guess though. :)

Comment: Did you remember to downscale the liquid a tiny bit to not having it intersect with the glass mesh?

Comment: @sorenfroststaal yup! the issue i'm working on is the slight change in refraction that happens on the glass itself. it's most visible where the white reflections on the left and right of the glass get cut off over the wine.