# Subdivision surface problem 1

Tags: modifiers, subdivision-surface

Please help. As I am facing a problem regarding this modifier.
all other edges and faces are fine but few edges and facing are stuck to Vertices/ Edges and are not smooth. The crease of all edges is 0.[image]

Comment: Hello :). This can happen when one of the faces orientation is flipped.

Comment: Related: [Inaccurate shading on object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/165080/78972)

Answer (score 3):

You probably have flipped normals.

[image: Flipped normals]

You can check your normals from Face Orientation under Overlays. Blue is outside and red is inside.

[image: Recalculate outside]

You can fix it in Edit Mode by pressing <kbd>a</kbd> to select all vertices and from Mesh tab under Normals press Recalculate Outside.

Comment: i guess this was the issue.