# Subsurface choke on a vertice

Tags: vertices, subdivision-surface

I am trying to put a subsurface modifyer to my model but it seems that the subsurface is choking on a vertide and I don't know why nor how to solve it. here is some screens

[image]

[image]

for some reason blender wants to choke on the highlighted vertice. I tried to remove it and redo my model but the result is the same

Any help please ?
Thanks

Comment: Try this https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/195354/subdivision-surface-problem-1 
If this works, please label your post as [ Duplicate ]