# Design dyson roller with unknown broken area

Tags: modeling, transforms

I am new in Blender, and doing hard to learn that. I was trying to made a Dyson vacuum cleaner parts by Blender and I made it, but the final model has a problem that I don't know why and how to fix it.

This is what it looks like in the object mode, I saw this problem after I have add solidity and subdivision on it:
[image: vaccum cleaner parts in object model]

This is the rendered image with clear broken area:
[image]

This is what it looks like in edit mode and without solidity and subdivision:
[image]

In my mind I haven't made any N-gon in these area, so I don't know why it happens, could anyone tell me the reason of that and how should I avoid on next time?

Here is the source file:
[Blender File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kgm9ypnpt0ck0it/dyson.blend?dl=0)

Thank you very much for reading this thread.

Comment: Hello :). You have flipped faces, you need to recalculate normals. There are also double verts and other non-manifold geometry.

Comment: Related: [Inaccurate shading on object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/165080/78972)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply! But I don't understand why I have flipped faces, I almost did it face by face myself, and double vertices also. Could you please some references that I can know more about that? thank you once again

Comment: Hey :). Flipped faces just happen during modeling, there can be many reasons. The same with double verts. But neither are big deal and easy to deal with :). Related: [What is Non-Manifold geometry](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7910/78972)

Comment: Thank you so much for such kind of help! Thank you!

Comment: No problem :). Good luck on your Blender journey :).

Answer (score 1):

After viewing your model, here's what I did:
#select the meshes then ctrl+A to apply all transformation.
#select the object go to edit mode and select all the vertex by pressing A once or twice. And then shift+N to recalculate normals.

Your mesh had some flipped normals which caused the issue you marked.  [Here's the File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16QSQfeAkqOpEl-wTomnGXIGy0czp2SaN/view?usp=sharing) after applying the fixes I mentioned.

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for your help! I really need to search the meaning of these actions then! thank you!