# crease in model when subdividing

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface

When subdividing I get a giant crease down the middle of my models face. I'm relatively new to 3D modeling and would appreciate any help that is given.
I have a mirror modifier and subdivision modifier on. I'm not sure what other information I would need to give. If more information is needed please let me know. Thank you for anyone that helps.

This is when the model isn't subdivided.
[image: not subdivided Yosh]

**this is when it's subdivided**

[image: Subdivided Yosh]

Comment: hello, maybe you have inner faces or overlapping vertices? Have you tried a Merge by Distance? Please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Hello :). My bet is on flipped faces: [Inaccurate Shading on Object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/165080/78972)

Comment: Sorry about the late response. I also go to school full-time and work. How do I share my blender file? unless, I upload to google drive then you download from there. I have tried merge by distance...It didn't work sadly.
And hello ^_^

The normals needed to be recalculated! Thank you for your help! Now I just have to clean this mess....

Answer (score 0):

Credit goes to Jachym Michal

"Hello :). My bet is on flipped faces: Inaccurate Shading on Object – Jachym Michal 22 hours ago"

It's in the comments, just recalculate normals to face outside, a (selects all) -> Shift-N