# Why are some faces darker than others in edit mode?

Tags: topology

Everything else is fine, it's not ngon or something, it's a quad, so why does this happens?

[image: It's not ngon or something, why does this happens?]
[image]
[image: Quad]
[image: Everyghing else is fine]

Comment: Hello :). Does this answer your question? [Inaccurate shading on object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165080/inaccurate-shading-on-object)

Comment: it would really help if you get the screenshots from another angle

Comment: Used this: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/vertex_connect.html On these [![///](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0B4gt.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0B4gt.png) and it helped!