# Strange dark color and reflection spots on solid mode

Tags: modeling, mesh, 3d-view, normals

I am new to Blender. My model appear darker with strange white reflections/spots, even on *Solid Mode*.

[image]

Parts that are disconnected from the main body are fairer for some reasons, and the mirror modifier edge has more spots than other places (when I deactivate the *Mirror modifier*, those spots disappear).

Those spots are visible in material preview too

[image]

The texture is completely homogeneous, and it is not the weight painting, right? Must have activated a special view or something.

[image]

I think I must have pressed a shortcuts while working on it. I tried copy-paste it on a new blend file, but the problem is copied with it. Complete new blend file don't have this problem, though.*

How do I repair it?

Or, in worst case, is there a way to only copy vertices (without the problematic properties) into a new blend file?

Comment: hello, could you please share some vertices of your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: This is probably custom normals

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are some faces in my mesh darker?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/why-are-some-faces-in-my-mesh-darker) and [inaccurate shading on object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165080/inaccurate-shading-on-object)