# Weird shading problems

Tags: shaders

Anyone knows how to fix this weird shading without having to delete the faces ? I don't want to delete the faces and adding them again to not ruin the UV map. Also all the faces normals points in right direction so I don't know what is causing this.

[image][image]

Comment: Hello :) Perhaps related: [Inaccurate shading on object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/165080/78972)

Comment: Also avoid ngons (so yes, you may have to redo some faces)