# Viewport shading issue

Tags: mesh, 3d-view, geometry, shadows

I am beginner at Blender and have been having this issue in the viewport shading mode. For some reason it gives me these funny shading problems which as far as I have found don't seem to be caused by anything like an extra face sitting in the same place or anything it might be some setting problem.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That really does look like overlapping geometry to me. Are you sure there isn’t either a copy of your object in the exact same place (try selecting one and hitting H for ‘hide’) or some geometry in the mesh (try goi into wireframe mode, select a nearby vertex and move it and see if anything is left behind).

Comment: Thankyou Rich Sedman, i tried that it figures there was a edge hanging there i deleted it but know like a few faces are shaded dark and a few are shaded light and theres like this hard cut between them, would you like me to share a picture?

Comment: @Bal_Lu Hey :). The second problem you're describing sounds like flipped normals: [Inaccurate shading on Object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/165080/78972)

Comment: Wonderful! Thankyou So Much @JachymMichal