# subdivision for object from loop cut result

Tags: subdivision-surface, bevel

This is my object/mesh
[image]

Actually I want to use bevel modifier but the result not what I want.

[image]

Then I try using subdivision modifier to check what's wrong with my object. And this is the result[image]

The left side is fine. Why does the right side behave like that? Is it because the right side is a loop cut result? [image]

Comment: Hello :). This can happen when one of your faces is inverted.

Comment: Related: [Inaccurate shading on object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/165080/78972)

Comment: @JachymMichal you are right! Thank you so much

Comment: Happy to help, good luck with your project :).