# Bridge edge loops is converting a circle to an octagon how do I fix this?

Tags: modeling

I am trying to attach a hand to an arm at the wrist via the bridge edge loops function. For some reason after I use the function the circle that was on the hand becomes an octagon creating little peaks around the wrist. What can I do to fix this?

I've tried moving the vertices inward but that just makes the octagon smaller, I've also tried adding subdivisions and attempting to recreate the circle. Also this may or may not be relevant but, I can create a duplicate circle from the hand and bridge to the arm just fine, everything stays as a circle, the issue seem to only exists on the actual hand circle.

Below is a download link for my project.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/bppqej1bdo9f67k/Fidget-2.blend?dl=0

[image]

The above is before bridging edge loops

[image]

The above is after bridging edge loops

[image]

The above illustrates the peaks being formed

Comment: maybe your faces are flipped? try to recalculate the normals in Edit mode

Comment: or you provide your blend file so we don't have to guess what the reason could be....

Comment: @JachymMichal the circles are both 8 vertices so I don't believe that's the issue.

Comment: @moonboots I'm very new to Blender, how would I go about your solution

Comment: @Chris as requested a dropbox link has been provided

Comment: thanks, i 'll check it out

Comment: Hey @Phlap :). To check and recalculate normals (as suggested by moonboots) see this thread: [Inaccurate shading on object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/165080/78972)

Comment: @moonboots What you commented was correct

Comment: @JachymMichal Thank you for the link!

Answer (score 1):

select vertices like i did:

[image]

then bridge edge loops

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, it looks like you bridged the 'feet' to the leg in your solution, I only have an issue bridging the hands to the arm. Which is bizarre because I'm following the same method for feet as I did for the hands. Regardless I followed your solution, applying it to the hand and arm, which unfortunately did not work.