# How can I fix this shading problem?

Tags: shaders, topology, retopology, polycount

First month using blender, familiar with character modeling and proper topology. Ever since I started on the legs of this character, I've noticed awkward shading where it shouldn't be, but I figured adding a Subdivision Modifier afterwards would solve the issue (it didn't), so I didn't pay much attention to it. My topology seems fine, and I've tried deleting faces around the area and refilling them. Is there a way to solve this issue?

[image: Shade Smooth]

[image: Shade Flat]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org). Photos are harder to read because we have to look past external interferences (like reflections, smudges or Moiré patterns) and guess if we are looking at hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connections, a software level issue like driver malfunction or glitch, or actual artifacts or issues with the model itself.

Comment: Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165080/inaccurate-shading-on-object