# Subdivision or quad issues

Tags: subdivision-surface, knife-tool

I've created this speaker mesh just as a test, but you can see one of my circles I've cut into the plane works smoothly and the other doesn't. Just unsure as to why. I have a subsurf modifier which I think may be causing it but open to any thoughts.

[image]

Still learning... Thanks all[image]

Comment: Perhaps Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/165081/78972

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to edit mode, select all and press Shift N (Recalculate Normals Outside).

Comment: Nice one thanks Josh — didn't think of this, all osrted, appreciate that thank you